# Why does HCl both precipitate and dissolve Silver?

Tags: silver

Adding $\ce{HCl}$ to silver nitrate solution causes silver chloride to precipitate. Adding more $\ce{HCl}$ causes the silver to re-dissolve. What is happening to the silver chloride when it re-dissolves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The precipitation reaction is:
$$\ce {Ag+ + Cl- -> AgCl_{(s)}}$$
The next reaction is:
$$\ce {AgCl_{(s)} +Cl- -> AgCl2- }$$

Comment: It might be useful to include the equilibrium constants for the two reactions: AgCl's k_sp is 1.77e-10 (so 5.6e9 for the equation as written), and the k_f for AgCl2- is 1.1e5.